# Using "ORDER BY" changes results of query

Tags: mysql, sql

I was recently working through the SQL tutorial for [Self Join](http://sqlzoo.net/wiki/Self_join).

The table definitions given are quite simple:

```
stops(id, name)
route(num, company, pos, stop)
```

Here, the `stop` attribute refers to the `id` of the stop which is provided a name in the `stops` table.

If you look at problem #10, I put in the following solution which the site indicates yields the correct results:

```
SELECT distinct a.num, a.company, bstops.name, e.num, e.company FROM route a
   JOIN route b ON (a.company = b.company AND a.num = b.num)
   JOIN stops bstops ON bstops.id = b.stop
   JOIN
     (SELECT c.company, c.num, d.stop as d_stop FROM route c
        JOIN route d ON (c.company = d.company AND c.num = d.num)
        WHERE c.stop = 213) e
     ON e.d_stop = b.stop
   WHERE a.stop = 53
```

Here, I already know that the `id` for `Craiglockhart` is `53`, and the `id` for `Sighthill` is `213`. All good so far.

But if I add an `ORDER BY name` or `ORDER BY bstops.name` to the query, the results change and more results are found:

```
SELECT distinct a.num, a.company, bstops.name, e.num, e.company FROM route a
   JOIN route b ON (a.company = b.company AND a.num = b.num)
   JOIN stops bstops ON bstops.id = b.stop
   JOIN
     (SELECT c.company, c.num, d.stop as d_stop FROM route c
        JOIN route d ON (c.company = d.company AND c.num = d.num)
        WHERE c.stop = 213) e
     ON e.d_stop = b.stop
   WHERE a.stop = 53 ORDER BY name
```

Specifically, for example, there are now 8 rows for London Road instead of just 4.

I've been playing with different queries trying to understand these results. Is there a reason `ORDER BY` should change the actual results of the query besides sorting?

Comment: I suppose that they add a "LIMIT BY" in the background - the number of rows returned is 50 in both cases, but the different order causes different records to be displayed as these first 50 records

Comment: @lurker . . . Do `select count(*)` to see how many rows really should be returned.  The number is probably greater than 50.

Comment: @Andreas oh right! Good grief, thanks, that's a good catch. And Gordon, I tried your `count(*)` as a check to verify Andreas' theory. It's all good. Thanks, that was dumb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can limit the number of records returned by using the `LIMIT` keyword on your query. I suppose that they are adding something like

```
... LIMIT 50 ...
```

to the query you are submitting, in order to avoid too many records to be returned.

Then, these first 50 records which are displayed can differ for different `ORDER BY` expressions, since the records are ordered first and then the ordered result is limited.

Suppose you have this `table`:

```
Id Name
--+-------
0 |Andreas
1 |Lurker
2 |Gordon
3 |John
```

Then,

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY Id LIMIT 2;

Id Name
--+-------
0 |Andreas
1 |Lurker
```

while

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY Name LIMIT 2;

Id Name
--+-------
0 |Andreas
2 |Gordon
```

Comment: Thanks, you caught the issue. I had forgotten to take into account the built-in LIMIT they have on that site when I got what it called "correct" results. My sanity and SQL universe order have been restored. :)

Answer (score 1):

Unless Scottish buses stop at the same stop regardless of the direction of travel, then I think the answer provided by SQLZOO is wrong.

I think you can emulate their answer with this query...

```
 SELECT a.num first_bus
      , a.company first_company
      , s1.name departing_from
      , s2.name interchange
      , d.num second_bus
      , d.company second_company
      , s3.name arriving_at
   FROM route a
   JOIN route b
     ON b.num = a.num

    AND b.pos <> a.pos

   JOIN route c
     ON c.stop = b.stop
   JOIN route d
     ON d.num = c.num

    AND d.pos <> c.pos

   JOIN stops s1
     ON s1.id = a.stop
   JOIN stops s2
     ON s2.id = b.stop
   JOIN stops s3
     ON s3.id = d.stop
  WHERE s1.name = 'Craiglockhart'
    AND s3.name = 'Sighthill';
```

However, I think the correct answer would be the result of...

```
 SELECT a.num first_bus
      , a.company first_company
      , s1.name departing_from
      , s2.name interchange
      , d.num second_bus
      , d.company second_company
      , s3.name arriving_at
   FROM route a
   JOIN route b
     ON b.num = a.num

    AND b.pos > a.pos

   JOIN route c
     ON c.stop = b.stop
   JOIN route d
     ON d.num = c.num

    AND d.pos > c.pos

   JOIN stops s1
     ON s1.id = a.stop
   JOIN stops s2
     ON s2.id = b.stop
   JOIN stops s3
     ON s3.id = d.stop
  WHERE s1.name = 'Craiglockhart'
    AND s3.name = 'Sighthill';
```

Comment: Yes, I think you are correct about SQLZOO. It's just an exercise so they take a simplistic view of the stated problem and, in my opinion also, it isn't always logically the totally correct answer. In this case, they didn't explain the `pos` attribute and never indicated that it should be taken into consideration.